# A web app isn't visible from the Internet

Tags: firewall, freebsd, web

I have a ruby webapp running on the port 5555 on FreeBsd 11. For some reason it's not visible from the Internet at all, although ipfw isn't running.

```
$ curl -i 12.34.55.66:5555
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 12.34.55.66:5555 port 5555: Connection refused
```

But the app is visible from that server, from localhost:

```
curl -i 0.0.0.0:5555
[....returns data]

curl -i 127.0.0.1:5555
[....returns data]
```

What can be the reason?

**update:**

```
$ sockstat
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS      
user123  ruby       93839 7  tcp6   ::1:5555              *:*
user123  ruby       93839 8  tcp4   127.0.0.1:5555        *:*
```

Comment: can you add the output of ``netstat -tlpn|grep 5555``?

Comment: Does your server have a public ip assigned on the network interface or it has a private ip? please provide the output of the command provided by allo

Comment: @allo netstat: illegal option -- t

Comment: @BogdanStoica yes

Comment: do you have any firewall running on the server?!

Comment: Are you running `curl -i 12.34.55.66:5555` from the local machine itself (won't work) or from an external machine? Also, as @BogdanStoica notes, is your machine NAT'd? Do you have a public or private IP?

Comment: @Joichi ok, seem to be a gnu option then. Anyway, look to which ip the server binds, you can connect to 0.0.0.0:5555 on the local machine even when its bound to 127.0.0.1. And typical dev-servers bind to localhost by default.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure whether this applies here, but some ruby webservers like e.g. `webrick` (the default webserver for Rails) do not bind to your external IP by default. So this might not even be a problem with your firewall, but just a missing configuration. Given the output of `sockstat`, this might be the case here. For `webrick`, you should pass `-b x.x.x.x` to the command to bind the server to your external IP address.

Comment: where did I say Rails?

Comment: That was an example. Your application is not binding to your external IP, that's your problem. Since you did not write which webapp you are using you have to find out yourself on how to configure it properly.

Comment: @duenni and you don't need to know what app it is.

Comment: You didn't say Rails. I took `webrick` as an example as that is a very common webserver in ruby development environments (since it's the Rails default). I'm assuming that you're approaching this machine from another system and that the IP is publicly available. But since you give as little information as you're currently doing, we're all guessing here.